# only 1 record coming instead of multiple records in the model in c#

Tags: c#

im getting only 1 row multiple times instead of getting multiple records. same record getting multiple times in the datatable and model.

```
 List<Trans_energycons_ReportModel> model = new List<Trans_energycons_ReportModel>();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("constr"))
                { 
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd_get_transformer_consumption = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
       Date,units from Total_Power", con);
                    SqlDataAdapter da_get_trans_consumption = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd_get_transformer_consumption);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da_get_trans_consumption.Fill(dt);
                    Trans_energycons_ReportModel m = new Trans_energycons_ReportModel();
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        string deviceDate = row["Date"].ToString();
                        string units = row["units"].ToString();
                        m.DeviceDate =Convert.ToDateTime(deviceDate);
                        m.Units =Convert.ToDouble(units);
                        model.Add(m);
                    }

                }
                return View(model);
```

Comment: Try definiting Trans_energycons_ReportModel in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the object is created before `foreach`, The object will be replaced with new entries all the time. Add `Trans_energycons_ReportModel m = new Trans_energycons_ReportModel();` inside `foreach`

```
List<Trans_energycons_ReportModel> model = new List<Trans_energycons_ReportModel>();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("constr"))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd_get_transformer_consumption = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Date,units from Total_Power", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da_get_trans_consumption = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd_get_transformer_consumption);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da_get_trans_consumption.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string deviceDate = row["Date"].ToString();
        string units = row["units"].ToString();

        //Create object here
        Trans_energycons_ReportModel m = new Trans_energycons_ReportModel();
        m.DeviceDate = Convert.ToDateTime(deviceDate);
        m.Units = Convert.ToDouble(units);
        model.Add(m);
    }

}
return View(model);
```

Comment: you are welcome @krishnamohan. you can mark this as an Answer